# Retrieve text between two periods in a value

Tags: sql, azure-synapse

I’ve been spinning around a bit on how to accomplish this in SQL DW.  I need to extract the text between two periods in a returned value.  So my value returned for Result is:

[image: ![enter image description here]

I’m trying to extract the values between period 1 and 2, so the red portion above:

[image]

The values will be a wide variety of lengths.

I’ve got this code:
`substring(Result,charindex('.',Result)+1,3) as ResultMid`
that results in this:

[image]

My problem is I’m not sure how to get to a variable length to return so that I can pull the full value between the two periods.  Would someone happen to know how I can accomplish this?

Thx,
Joe

Comment: Does the text you are extracting always come before .sys and the first period?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  I have .np.sys as well, and in the future maybe more.  So I'm trying to build a rule that will always pull between period 1 and period 2.

Comment: Okay so it's always between the first and the 2nd period, correct?

Comment: If your SQL database supports regex like REGEXP_SUBSTR you could use this regex: '\.[^\.]+\.' .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can build on your current attempt:

```
substring(
    result,
    charindex('.', result) + 1,
    charindex('.', result, charindex('.', result) + 1) - charindex('.', result) - 1
)
```

Rationale: you alreay have the first two arguments to `substring()` right. The third argument defines the number of characters to capture. For this, we compute the position of the *next* dot (`.`) with expression: `charindex('.', result, charindex('.', result) + 1)`. Then we substract the position of the first dot from that value, which gives us the number of characters that we should capture.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=253a8a4e817ab78adcc4bfe1deee6c46)**:

```
result                   | result_mid
:----------------------- | :---------
sam.pdc.sys.paas.l.com   | pdc       
sm.ridl.sys.paas.m.com   | ridl      
s.sandbox.sys.paas.g.com | sandbox
```

Comment: Bingo! Works great!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with up to 128 characters per delimited part of the string, try `parsename` as below. Otherwise, GMB has a pretty solid solution up there.

```
select *, parsename(left(result,charindex('.',result,charindex('.',result)+1)-1),1) as mid
from your_table;
```

Another method that you can easily modify to extract 3rd, 4th...(hopefully not too remote) part of the string using `cross apply`.

```
select result, mid
from your_table t1
cross apply (select charindex('.',result) as i1) t2
cross apply (select charindex('.',result,(i1 + 1)) as i2) t3
cross apply (select substring(result,(i1+1),(i2-i1-1)) as mid) t4;
```

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2f46c51fa28e128877cbea3f3cac5172)**

Comment: Interesting, I've never used cross apply.  Nice method.  Thanks